# I did a restart Windows Explorer (Windows 10) from the Task Manager. The volume would not open. How long should this run? It has been 2 hours

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, reboot

The computer seems to be running fine. Email, search, internet and the volume. Is this too long? What happens when it is timeto do a restart of the computer for the night if this is still running? Thank you. Pat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The computer seems to be running fine. Email, search, internet and the
> volume.

Close Windows Explorer with Task Manager.

Look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance. Pull down Maintenance. You will likely see that Windows Explorer has "Stopped Working". Two hours is too long for it to do anything.

Windows Explorer is built right into Windows, so the way to fix this is with a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Microsoft Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: Hi John- I did a backup to a thumb drive (I hope) and ended Windows Explorer in the Task Manager. The Start and bottom taskbar are gone. Thank you.

Comment: You should do the Repair as I suggested.

Comment: Hi John - I did the repair as you suggested. It just finished up. Lots of updates. Thank you so much. Pat

Comment: Thanks for the update and I was happy to help